# win32print and multiple printers

Tags: python, windows, pdf, printing, win32com

I should print a local pdf file, if printer_name is defined (a normal string) the program should send the document to a specific printer otherwise it should use the default printer.

This code works but use the default printer anyway!

```
global printer_name
if printer_name:
    print "printer",nome_stampante
else:
    nome_stampante = win32print.GetDefaultPrinter()
    print "default printer"

out = '/d:"%s"' % nome_stampante

win32api.ShellExecute (
    0,
    "print",
    filename,
    out,
    ".",
    0
)
```

Where is the mistake?

many thanks

Answer (score 2):

Your code use global variables and nobody knows where `printer_name` is set and what is in `nome_stampante`. I propose you to use function that will print file using chosen printer. This can look like:

```
import win32api
import win32print

def win_print(filename, printer_name = None):
    if not printer_name:
        printer_name = win32print.GetDefaultPrinter()
    out = '/d:"%s"' % (printer_name)
    win32api.ShellExecute(0, "print", filename, out, ".", 0)


def test_print():
    win_print('test.txt')
    win_print('test.txt', 'PDFCreator')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    test_print()
```

Comment: This works for me -- test program produces 2 PDF files. As for print command in my registry I have: `%SystemRoot%\system32\NOTEPAD.EXE /p %1`

Comment: Yes, PDFCreator is also my default printer :)

Comment: sorry, nome_stampante is "printer_name" in Italian. Anyway I changed the verb and now it works